# Swift hierarchy cannot load the menu

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am new to Swift, and am facing an issue with the following hierarchy:

```
UITabBarController > UINavigationController > FirstViewController:UIViewController > PageMenu
```

The above hierarchy cannot load the menu, while the `UIViewController` seems cover/hide it, even using this:

```
[self = FirstViewController:UIViewController]

class FirstViewController {

...viewDidLoad() {
      ....
      addChildViewController(pageMenuViewController)
      view.addSubview(pageMenuViewController)
      pageMenuViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
   }
}
```

The default `FirstViewController` label always shows on top - I am using the Xcode default `tabBarController` setting (i.e., got First and Second view) and try to replace the FirstView with the `PageMenuViewController` above.

`self.view.addSubview(pageMenuViewController)` in `FirstViewController` is not working correctly.

Comment: Are you doing this through storyboards or programmatically?  You're saying that you have a TabBar Controller which has a FirstViewController item (embedded in a Navigation Controller). The FirstViewController has on it a PageViewController, right? Can you take a screenshot of your storyboard so that we can better see your scene flow?

Comment: all settings are in storyboards at first (since I am using the default Apple tabBarController) then all I would like to do is to "programatically" load my PageMenuViewController to the FirstViewController. The storyboard is like this: UITabBarController > UINavigationController > FirstViewController:UIViewController - try make a new project in xcode and choose TabBarApplication then you get what I mean. Thanks for asking too :)